# Question about lim sup

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are two real sequences such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$.  Is it true that

$$\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = a + \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} b_n$$

Comment: This was not the question, @NasuSama.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true.  One easy way to prove it is to use the characterization of lim sup as the largest subsequential limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider that for any $\epsilon\gt0$, we can find an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$,
$$
|a_n-a|\le\epsilon/2
$$
and there is some $m\ge N$ so that
$$
b_m\ge\limsup_{k\to\infty}b_k-\epsilon/2
$$
Now you just need to show that for any $\epsilon\gt0$ and $N$ we can find some $m\ge N$ so that
$$
a_m+b_m\ge a+\limsup_{k\to\infty}b_k-\epsilon
$$